# Organizing the directory structure of my DDD-based web application?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, directory-structure

I have started to look away from the normal MVC way of creating my web applications and have had a look at Domain Driven Design - DDD.

From having `Models` alone, I now have `Collections`, `Entities`, `DataMappers` & `Repositories` in my application to work with. Full-fledged separation and modularity for sure, but now my directory structure is nothing but a complete mess!

As I have never worked with a DDD-application in the past, I have little idea on how to organize my file structure.

**Would below be an appropriate directory structure?**
Note: I am using PHP5, but I reckon this question to be close to language-agnostic.

```
/application
    /common
        /libraries
        /helpers
    /temp
        /cache
    /domain
        /collections
        /entities
        /datamappers
        /repositories
    /ui
        /controllers
        /view
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think that makes sense, but, that is going to separate your modules into *what layer they are at*, rather then *what they do*. For example, in this structure, if you wanted an Authentication and printing modules, you would have probably something like this:

```
    /common
        /helpers
             /Authentication
                 /AuthenticationService.php
             /Printing
                 /PrintingService.php
    /domain
        /entities
             /Authentication
                 /Identity.php
             /Printing
                 /Printer.php
        /datamappers
             /Authentication
                 /IdentityDataMap.php
             /Printing
                 /PrinterDataMap.php
```

Having worked in a system like this, I can say for one thing, it gets very hard to keep the boundaries between modules from inter-meshing, just because humans are working in the layers, and thinking of the layers as 'all together'. Just from an organizational standpoint, I don't really like having to have three root level directories open to work with a particular module. We organize projects into directories to make it easier for us to deal with, not the compiler.

If I was doing it again, I would separate *some* things by layer, say UI code, on one level, and business code on another, but then by module under that. More of a hybrid I suppose, but perhaps better for it.

```
    /domain
        /Printing
            /entities
            /datamappers
            /repositories
        /Auth
            /entities
            /datamappers
            /repositories
    /ui
        /controllers
        /view
```

Comment: where would you put your value objects?